# Can php wait for a very long time before responding to an ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to make a chat site where the js AJAXs to PHP and the PHP waits for the database to change from what the user has then it responds to the user and the user again in the recall function AJAXs the server and so on. I would like to call the same server holding the request to add any chat that the user wants to add. I would like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could but that doesn't mean you should.

Just for the idea, you can make a loop with `sleep()` inside the loop, and also a script that checks for changes in the database, once the database has changed then you return your message and get out of the loop. However this will leave your server with lots of processes and connections.

An alternative is to use websocket which is designed for real-time messaging and more suited for this task.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think its possible. PHP is stateless unlike other languages such as Node.JS, meaning the server cant tell the client (browser) what to do unless specifically requested by the client in the first place. Browsers or servers usually have a timeout set anyway, so your method of having a realtime chat wouldn't work like this.

Rather, I think your only solution might be to make your ajax call e.g every 0.5s and ask the server if there is any new message, and if so, return it back to the client.

Comment: You can set the timeout on the server and the client did call the server in ajax.

Comment: Realistically it is not always possible to control the timeouts. In fact many shared hosts or webservers have firewalls behind that limit the timeout which you are not able to control, even if you paid for the hosting. Also, it is definitely not a good idea to keep a connection open indefinitely just to wait for a response. What if the server doesn't respond at all? Is the client just going to wait forever? PHP isn't suited for realtime chat messaging in the first place, but if u must, you should definitely follow my suggestion if you have no viable solutions.